# Viewing mesh outline in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, animation

In the tutorial I am viewing online, the teacher is able to view the mesh outline without the mesh triangles by selecting the mesh in the effects list within the layer. Its unclear even from putting the question into Google how to do this? Can anyone help? Hopefully the attached image illustrates what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling paths and alike by clicking on the button next to the one for your safe areas and rulers.

Can't upload a screenshot unfortunately, Stackexchange keeps crashing when I try...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It seems that the outline of the mesh only appears when the puppet starch tool is used rather than the regular puppet tool.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Glad you found the solution :)